# Could not chdir to home directory after create a user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I've created a user in Ubuntu 16.04 using the commands

```
sudo useradd peris
sudo passwd peris
```

Then I log off, ans log in with the new user but I got this error:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/peris: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automatically create the user's home directory you have to call:

```
sudo useradd -m peris
```

From now on, the best you can do is manually create the user's home directory using:

```
sudo mkdir /home/peris
```

And set the user's home directory so the system actually knows where to go. This can be done using:

```
sudo usermod -d /home/peris peris
```

Also, you want to make sure the said user has rights on his own folder. Use:

```
sudo chown peris:peris /home/peris
```